# How to reverse a string in processing?

Tags: processing

I have been searching a lot online for a solution to this, but here is my question. 
Basically I need to reverse a string of 4 characters: ABCD becomes DCBA.

Here is the start of the program:

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

String input;

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string with 4 characters (e.g. ABCD): " );
```

Thanks

Comment: At least give us valid Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do it in Java.

```java
String output = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
```

You could also use a `for` loop to loop over the characters and build the `String` yourself.

Comment: Is there by any chance, a simpler way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @MyName This is a one-line solution. How much simpler could it possibly be? I've given you the options: use `StringBuilder`, or use a `for` loop. There isn't a "simpler" way to do it, because those are both about as simple as you can possibly get.